# Install Oracle Weblogic: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, redhat

I tried to install Oracle Weblogic on Redhat Linux 8

using command

```
java -jar fmw_12.2.1.4.0_wls_quick.jar
```

but got an error:

```
Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Java version

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
```

Then I switched to a higher java version, which is:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
```

Then I got an error:

```
The OpenJDK JVM is not supported on this platform
```

What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"openJDK" is not listed within the Supported Configuration documents.
https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/fusion-certification.html

Use Oracle JDK.

Comment: just to add more information, I downloaded JDK 8 from here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html 
then it works just fine